# How to send parameter to route on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, laravel, routes

I have the following route:

```
Route::get("/changeLang/{lang}", 'SiteController@changeLang');
```

And I have the following form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/changeLang/???') }}" method="GET">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="lang">
        <option value="eng">English</option>
        <option value="cro">Hrvatski</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

So I'd like to submit that form to that route so that the route receives the language that the user selected. I don't know should form method be GET or POST.

So how do I specify link to that route in form action so that the selected language gets sent? What to put instead of those question marks at the end of the URL?

And I don't like to use Laravel's Form facade (or is it just class) to echo HTML elements, so I'd like to do it without that if possible.

Comment: well form submission is not going to work since it would be `/changeLang/lang?lang=cro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not submit a form and have it generate a URL in the format that you are expecting. What is going to happen is you will get a URL in the format of `/changeLang/lang?lang=cro`

So you have two options. You submit the form and it redirects based off the querysting value.

OR you add JavaScript to your form so you produce the url that you are after.

```
<select onchange="window.location.href='/changeLang/' + this.value;" name="lang">
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to me that route name musn't be in camelCase but in snake_case. If I try it with camel case it actually goes to /change_lang/lang=cro and can't find that route.

Answer (score 1):

if your route is something like this.

```
Route::get("/changeLang", 'SiteController@changeLang');
```

your form will be something like this.

```
<form action="{{ url('/changeLang') }}" method="GET">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="lang">
    <option value="eng">English</option>
    <option value="cro">Hrvatski</option>
</select>
```

to get value from `GET`[`POST` optionally after changing route], in your `controller` do something like this.

```
public function changeLang(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    //echo $request->lang;
    // or you can access data like this.
    echo $data['lang'];
}
```

and if you want this route

```
Route::get("/changeLang/{lang}", 'SiteController@changeLang');
```

then you need to append this to the route and  request url will be something like this.

> https://host/changeLang/eng

and in your controller.

```
public function changeLang($lang)
{
    echo $lang;
}
```

`url(route)`

> The url function generates a fully qualified URL to the given path

more about [`url`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url).

Hope this will help!.

Comment: well I get that but I don't know how to specify link to the route in HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<form action="{{ url('/changeLang', [$lang]) }}" method="GET">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="lang">
        <option value="eng">English</option>
        <option value="cro">Hrvatski</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Or this

```
<form action="{{ url('/changeLang/' . $lang,) }}" method="GET">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="lang">
        <option value="eng">English</option>
        <option value="cro">Hrvatski</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use laravel form builder:

```
{{ Form::open([
      'method' => 'GET',
      'action' => ['some@action', $param]
]) }}

...

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Or:

```
 <form action="{{ url('/changeLang/lang' . $param) }}" method="GET">
```